# Hive SQL count items and if it equals one tell what item was used

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, case, hiveql

I am querying users that use either Desktop or Mobile devices and I would like to tell whether they used only one or both of these in a single day and in case they used just one category, which one it was.

I compiled the query below but I am running in circle as I cannot use 'dev2' in GROUP BY clause before I count the 'dev_count'.

```
SELECT day, user,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
  WHEN dev = "SmartPhone" OR dev = "Tablet" 
    THEN "Mobile"
  ELSE "Desktop" 
END) AS dev_count,
CASE 
  WHEN dev_count = 1
    THEN
      CASE 
        WHEN dev = "SmartPhone" OR dev = "Tablet" 
          THEN "Mobile"
        ELSE "Desktop" 
        END
  ELSE ""
END AS dev2
FROM table1
WHERE
    ...
GROUP BY day, user, dev2
ORDER BY day;
```

Is there a way to get out of it?

Comment: sample data and table structure would help. but looking at your sql, just create a subquery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use collect_set() aggregation function to get array of UNIQUE used device types/etc, then you can use array_contains() to check what array contains and size() to check if it contains more than one element and get array[0] if it contains single element.

```
select day, user, 
       size(device_type_used_array) as dev_count,
       case when size(device_type_used_array)=1 
                then device_type_used_array[0] 
           else NULL --more than one, put what you want instead of NULL
       end as one_category_used
from
(
SELECT day, user, 
collect_set(CASE WHEN dev = "SmartPhone" OR
                      dev = "Tablet" 
                THEN "Mobile"
                ELSE "Desktop" 
           END) AS device_type_used_array
FROM table1
WHERE
    ...
GROUP BY day, user
)s
order by day;

device_type_used_array contains unique device type used per day. For not unique array use collect_list(), you can use both if necessary
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this ?

I used a subqry to calculate the count of devices used and then in outer query i am using case when to use it to determine its mobile or desktop.

```
SELECT day, user, 
dev_count,
CASE 
  WHEN dev_count = 1
    THEN
      CASE 
        WHEN dev = "SmartPhone" OR dev = "Tablet" 
          THEN "Mobile"
        ELSE "Desktop" 
        END
  ELSE ""
END AS dev2
FROM 
(SELECT day, user,
COUNT( CASE 
  WHEN dev = "SmartPhone" OR dev = "Tablet" 
    THEN "Mobile"
  ELSE "Desktop" 
END) AS dev_count
,dev
FROM table1
WHERE
    ...
GROUP BY day, user, dev) rs
ORDER BY day;
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you, but the problem here is still the one I faced: It shows count for each type of device as in the subquery the count is grouped by device_detection["device_type"].